# GetWindowsDirectory() API returns wrong (vba\vb6)

Tags: vba, winapi, vb6

on my **Windows-Terminal** user, I'm trying to have two application point to the same Windows directory, one written in VBA one in VB6.

When calling the [GetWindowsDirectory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724454(v=vs.85).aspx) API from VB6 it returns the correct path

> C:\documents and settings\%user%\Windows

When calling it from VBA macro, it returns

> C:\Windows

Notice that **same result goes for [GetSystemWindowsDirectory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724403(v=vs.85).aspx)**

Thiking may be the VBA code wasn't aware its a Terminal station, I called the `GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTESESSION)` API which returned 1, meaning it is aware that it is a terminal.

The exact same code was used in both VB6 and VBA

Windows 2003R2 , Office version is 2010 64bit (which as i'm typing this, makes me wonder if it's related, knowing vb6 is 32bit ...)

Any ideas ?

**EDIT:** as explained by IInspectable below, the difference between vba and vb6 is because vb6 is not Terminal-Service-Aware like Office is.

Comment: [_"This function is provided primarily for compatibility with legacy applications."_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724454(v=vs.85).aspx). What are you trying to do? Call `SHGetKnownFolderPath` with `FOLDERID_Windows` instead.

Comment: I meant "what do you expect"? What is "the same Windows directory"? Do you mean the Windows installation directory? See updated comment above.

Comment: [GetWindowsDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724454.aspx): *"If the application is Terminal-Services-aware (has the **IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE** flag set in the image header), this function returns the path of the system Windows directory, just as the [**GetSystemWindowsDirectory**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724403.aspx) function does. Otherwise, it retrieves the path of the private Windows directory for the user."*

Comment: @CodeCaster SHGetKnownFolderPath returned **C:\Windows ** .. CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(ssfWINDOWS           ).Self.Path

Comment: Yes, this is all very clearly documented

Comment: Which will die first, XP or VB6?...

Comment: @JonathanPotter both will remain as mummy, wrapped in vm´s

Comment: @Jonathan: Considering that [VB6 is supported all the way through Windows 8.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708), I'd guess that Windows XP will go first.

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* is not a question that should be asked on SO. I interpreted your initial question as: *"Why are the results different?"* and [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30863189/1889329) that. Updating a question to ask a different question is also not recommended. If you have another question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: I'm quite unhappy with all your question edits. @IInspectable answered the question that you asked. That you still have a problem to solve does not alter the fact that your question was answered. If you need help solving the problem, now that you have a clearer understanding, do ask another question. I suggest that you revert your edits, accept IInspectable's answer, and ask your new question. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you are observing is documented. See the *Remarks* section for [GetWindowsDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724454.aspx):

> **Terminal Services:** If the application is running in a Terminal Services environment, each user has a private Windows directory. There is also a shared Windows directory for the system. If the application is Terminal-Services-aware (has the **IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE** flag set in the image header), this function returns the path of the system Windows directory, just as the [**GetSystemWindowsDirectory**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724403.aspx) function does. Otherwise, it retrieves the path of the private Windows directory for the user.

The [DUMPBIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) tool with the [/HEADERS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ha900t8.aspx) option can be used to verify, whether the **IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE** flag is set for a binary.

```
dumpbin /HEADERS WINWORD.EXE
```

produces the following output (Microsoft Office 2013 32-bit):

```
OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             10B magic # (PE32)
                 ...
               2 subsystem (Windows GUI)
            8140 DLL characteristics
                   Dynamic base
                   NX compatible
                   Terminal Server Aware
                 ...
```

In other words: Microsoft Office is Terminal-Services-aware, and calling `GetWindowsDirectory` from a VBA script hosted inside Microsoft Office will return the shared Windows directory for the system.

If you checked your VB6 application with DUMPBIN, you'll see that it isn't Terminal-Services-aware, and calling `GetWindowsDirectory` will return the private Windows directory for the user.

---

Additional resources:

- [/TSAWARE (Create Terminal Server Aware Application)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01cfys9z.aspx)

Comment: Flawlessly explained. thank you. is there a bypass or another suggestion of how to retrieve the actual win folder from within an office application, within the boundaries of VBA ?

Comment: @polisha989: I'm not aware of a way to force `GetWindowsDirectory` to return the legacy (i.e. non Terminal-Services-aware) result. What do you get when calling [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) with [FOLDERID_Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457.aspx) from your VBA script?

Comment: getting C:\Windows, which is not what im after.